# BCP Error [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver 13]Unable to resolve column level collations

Tags: sql-server, bcp

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver 13]Unable to resolve column level collations

I have researched  in google and have not seen a solution.
The BCP works and then says *copying*. It even creates the text file. Then I get the above error and the text file is left empty.

I had **sql server 2014** and **sql server 2012** express installed on my machine and the server that the **BCP** is importing is **SQL Server 2008**.

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. I am a long time reader though.

Comment: Hello you down voters. There should be no down vote without a comment...

Comment: Can you include your query, the design of the tables it uses and the collation of each text column?

Comment: The problem is fixed. I deleted all installations of SQL Server including a SQL server 2016 part installation. I installed 2008r2 SQL Server. The query worked fine. I understand that collations come in to effect when going from database to database. The error was confusing as it was ambiguous as to whether it was a query error or a driver error. I was going from SQL Server to a text file. The query had unions in it. When I just did the query for a single select it worked. But when I did it for the select with union I got the above error.

Comment: But after the new single selection of SQL Server 2008r2 Express it works. I can not publish the BCP command with the query or the tables because they are sensitive. I thank you for your interest in my first StackOverflow question. Any constructive criticism would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Collations come into effect, whenever you try to sort, filter or join textual data (e.g. `varchar`).

This can be due to

- a specified collation in your script
- differing collations in the table columns you are querying
- differing collations in the databases (if you query against more than one database)
- and **last but not least!** a differing collation of the server itself. This means, that created temp tables (either `CREATE TABLE #tbl ...` or `SELECT * INTO #tbl ...`) will use a "wrong" collation as default.